# DetailView in Telerik MVC Grid Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc, detailview

Below is the current view I am using, I want to add `DetailView` to it. I have tried many examples even I used telerik demo code but none of the code seems to work. Can anyone show me some code how to do that. Each DetailView row should be filled with `"detailViewCategory"` as shown in model

**View**

```
   @(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.Mappings)        
                .Name("Grid")
                .Scrollable(c => c.Height("200px"))
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(o => o.nopCategoryID).Hidden(true);
                    columns.Bound(o => o.nopCategory).Width(100).Title("Category");                               

                    columns.Bound(e => e.ClockCategory).Width(200).Title("Mapped To").Template(t => t.ClockCategory.Replace(",", "<br />")); 

                    columns.Bound(o => o.nopCategoryID)
                                        .Width(50)
                                        .Centered()
                                        .Template(o => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditProduct", new { id = o.nopCategoryID }))
                                        .Title("Edit");
                    columns.Bound(o => o.nopCategoryID)
                                        .Width(50)
                                        .Centered()
                                        .Template(o => Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteMapping", new { id = o.nopCategoryID }))
                                        .Title("Delete");        
                })

                )
```

**Model**

```
    public class C_Category
    {
        public int nopCategoryID { get; set; }     
        public string nopCategory { get; set; }
        public string ClockCategory { get; set; }

        public DetailViewCategory detailViewCategory { get; set; }
    }
```

**DetailViewCategory**

```
public class DetailViewCategory
{
    public int nopCategoryID { get; set; }
    public int ClockCategoryID { get; set; }
    public string ClockCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.DetailView(details => details.ClientTemplate(

            Html.Telerik().TabStrip()
                .Name("TabStrip_<#= nopCategoryID#>")
                .SelectedIndex(0)
                .Items(items =>
                {
                    items.Add().Text("Details").LoadContentFrom("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { id = "<#= nopCategoryID#>"});
                })
                .ToHtmlString()
    ))
```